# PC Lint while(TRUE) vs for(;;)

Tags: c, embedded, lint, pc-lint

I'm using PC Lint for the first time. I was "linting" my code, when PC Lint warns me about my `while(TRUE)`.

This is what it says:

> 716: while(1) ...  -- A construct of the form while(1) ... was found.
>
> Whereas this represents a constant in a context expecting a Boolean,
>   it may reflect a programming policy whereby infinite loops are
>   prefixed with this construct. Hence it is given a separate number and
>   has been placed in the informational category. The more conventional
>   form of infinite loop prefix is for(;;).

I didn't understand this statement. Can anyone help me to understand it?

Comment: `while(TRUE)` may not be an infinite loop if some one sets `TRUE` to `0` while there is no way for that to happen with `for(;;)`.

Comment: @Dan D., sure there is - we are talking about the preprocessor after all. How about `#define for(;;) if(0)`? ;-)

Comment: I know what it's talking about but that's an odd explanation I have to say.

Comment: @PéterTörök: `#define for(;;) if(0)` is illegal because for(;;) is not an identifier and neither can it be parsed as a macro declaration

Comment: @Armen, fair enough, my C skills are rusty. I believe though there may easily be some twisted way to actually do it. And if someone is evil enough to redefine `TRUE`, he can just as well redefine `for` :-(

Comment: Nah, the common convention is while(42), ensures exit after 8 million years.  The arbitrarity of the value is enough reason to not use one, for(;;) is a great speed bump to a reader.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text says that although `while(TRUE)` (which gets preprocessed into `while(1)`) is a perfectly valid infinite loop, the more conventional form of writing an infinite loop is

```
for(;;)
{
   ...
}
```

because it doesn't use any values at all and therefore is less error-prone.

Answer (score 4):

It says that the more conventional infinite loop is `for(;;)`, which I'd say is an arguable assertion, and that it's categorized this construct as an "informational category" finding - I suspect that if you used the `for(;;)` instead it would go away.  I've always written these as `while(1)` and never `for(;;)` myself.  If it does what you expect, I'd ignore the findings of PC LINT on this one or switch it if you're worried about someone redefining `TRUE` because *if* someone redefined `TRUE` your loop wouldn't run at all.

Comment: And anyway, if someone redefined `TRUE`, it would be the least of your woes that a practicular loop doesn't run infinitely :-)